# How to replace IN clause when using huge list of included items/ids?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have sql which looks like this:

```
SELECT some_column FROM some_table WHERE some_column IN (v1, v2, v3, v4, ..., v100, v101, ... v1000, v1001, ... );
```

IN clause sometimes contains a lot of items/ids like 1000 or more. I'm not an sql expert, is there a way to solve this problem because performance is very low with this query? Some replacement for IN clause?

To be more precisely, values came from method:

```
public void slowQuery() {
    List<Integer> ids = getIds();
    String queryString = "SELECT some_column FROM some_table WHERE some_column IN :ids";
    Query query = getSession().createQuery(queryString);
    query.setParameter(ids, "ids");
    ....
}

public List<Integer> getIds() {
    List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    // run 4 queries to get data and put them into ids array

    return ids;
}
```

Comment: where do the values in the list come from? can they be got from another query? If so, show the query.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't paste these queries. So the problem might be that ids came from method instead of subqueries?

Comment: If the IDs come from straight from 4 queries (in getIds()) then you can put them in your IN clause directly... WHERE some_column IN (select id from query1 UNION select id from query2 UNION ...)

Comment: show the 4 queries that produce the ids. If they are long, edit them to leave just the essential parts

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to deal with this, depending on where the Ids come from the in the first place.

If the Ids come from some external system or a very convoluted process, then insert them into a temporary table.  Then modify your query to include:

```
WHERE ID IN (SELECT id FROM temp)
```

If the Ids come from a select out of the same database, then avoid bringing them over the network to your client software just to have them sent back again:-

```
WHERE ID IN ( SELECT ...however you find them now... )
```

In both of the above causes you may prefer to use a `INNER JOIN` than an `IN` list. It easier for me to explain with an `IN` clause because that more closely matches what you have now.

Answer (score 1):

First, create a VARRAY type:

```
create or replace TYPE the_list_type AS VARRAY (2000) OF INTEGER;
```

Then, create a stored procedure which accepts the "in list" as a string parameter, converts the list into the array, then runs the query using the array in the following type of construct:

```
select * from x
from dual
where id in (select column_value from table(cast(list_var as the_list_type)));
```

Write this to a ref cursor as the return parameter.

Now, amend your Java call to call this stored proc, passing the in list as csv, and read the return ref cursor.

See this example on how the build the stored proc:

https://community.oracle.com/thread/1071713?tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

Try to add items from `IN` clause to table and join this table to your `some_table`